# Sympy is automatically rewriting my equation

Tags: python, sympy

I have the following code:

```
import sympy as smp
from sympy import *
Pp = smp.symbols('Pp')
T = smp.symbols('T')
ET = Pp/smp.sqrt((0.9)+Pp**2/((300+25*T+0.05*T**3)**2))
```

Before adding the `**2` in the `(300+25T+0.05*T**3)` expression, the equation given by Sympy is what I am looking for:

[image]

However, when I include the `**2`, it turns into this:

[image]

I am expecting to get something like this:

[image]

Can anyone shed some light on how to do it please?

Comment: Are you sure they're not equivalent? sympi may have done some constant folding.

Answer (score 0):

Sympy is applying some kind evaluation strategy. Which strategy is not clear in this example, one would have to dig into the source code to find out.

Note that what you are asking for is non-trivial: we can get the expression pretty close to the form you are looking for, but not exactly. That's because there is no way (that I'm aware of) to easily asks SymPy to avoid evaluation at a global level.

In this particular example, we can convert floating point numbers to rationals inside the "problematic" term:

```py
ET = Pp/smp.sqrt((0.9)+Pp**2/(smp.nsimplify(300+25*T+0.05*T**3)**2))
```

Also note that when working with sympy, generally it's a good idea to use rationals instead of floats.

Answer (score 0):

Powers (with Rational exponents?) are made canonical so the largest coefficient is 1 in their base. You can get something more like what you want by replacing the "2" with `Symbol('2')`.